# How to use SubSonic with MS Access database

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to use subsonic with MS access MDB files?

Answer (score 3):

From the looks of things, no.  http://forums.subsonicproject.com/forums/t/2968.aspx Looks like an 'offline beta' was created, but looking at the thread there, looks like things ran into problems.  Access really is a different animal (it's a faux-db, for goodness sakes), so anyone willing to write a DAL like Subsonic would be targeting the real deal, like Oracle, MySQL, and MS SQL.  Any reason why you aren't at least using one of the [Express Editions of MS SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express.aspx)?  You'll certainly get more mileage, scalibility, and compatible tools by going that road.

Comment: Yeh, until recent versions, it supported more SQL features a complex queries than MySql. It might be file based rather than server based, and it might crash a lot with lots of concurrent users, but it's very much a real SQL database.

Comment: +1 since, while the Access bashing exists, the answer is valid with follow up resources to the subsonic forums.

Comment: Access is basically an IDE for the Microsoft Jet DB. So it is incorrect to call it a "faux-db".

Answer (score 0):

Its possible, the DataProvider is here

https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0/blob/master/SubSonic/DataProviders/AccessDataProvider.cs

together with the full project of subsonic.